# Sideshow with Title and description

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I've been looking for a sideshow with image, a short title and a long, multiline description. The plugin should also have basic common function like forward and backward option.
[image: Sample image of what I want]

**This will be used inside a table, so it should also adapt to the TD width** !

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the exact the slider you wanted but can make it like your's.
See this [basic jquery slider](http://basic-slider.com/).

And it's [github page](https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider/).

The difference is you need both title and description and it has only title.
But look at it's code you will see this

```
$.each($slides, function(key, slide) {

  var caption = $(slide).children('img:first-child').attr('title');

  // Account for images wrapped in links
  if (!caption) {
    caption = $(slide).children('a').find('img:first-child').attr('title');
  }

  if (caption) {
    caption = $('<p class="bjqs-caption">' + caption + '</p>');
    caption.appendTo($(slide));
  }

});
```

> Which is `attr` the images title and convert it to a `<p>`. You could
>   add another `data-description`. And could change the above code to..

```
$.each($slides, function(key, slide) {

  var caption = $(slide).children('img:first-child').attr('title');
  var description = $(slide).children('img:first-child').data('description');

  // Account for images wrapped in links
  if (!caption) {
    caption = $(slide).children('a').find('img:first-child').attr('title');
  }
  if (!description) {
    description = $(slide).children('a').find('img:first-child').data('description');
  }

  if (caption) {
    caption = $('<p class="bjqs-caption">' + caption + '</p>');
    caption.appendTo($(slide));
  }
  if (description) {
    description = $('<p class="bjqs-description">' + description + '</p>');
    description.appendTo($(slide));
  }

});
```

And css

```
p.bjqs-caption,
p.bjqs-description {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
p.bjqs-caption {
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
}
p.bjqs-description {
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, just a single  question. How to change the description paragraph to the bottom of the image ?

Comment: @Sourav Description will change with the every image slide. This will be a single image slide <img src="slide1.jpg" title="Your slide1 title" data-description="Your slide 1 description" />

Comment: I want to know how to place the position of the description from above the image to the bottom of the image.

Comment: @Sourav that's why i place the css see 'p.bjqs-caption' has bottom 70px which was originally 0, You can make it more upper may be 'bottom: 100px'

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Here's a custom slider using [bxSlider](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4) it is in a `td` that's in a `tr` that's in a `tbody` that's in a `table` of 2 rows and 3 columns. The slider is responsive i.e. (resizes and adjusts to screen size). The top half has images. The bottom half has various types of text, notice the height will adjust to the size of the text.

Best view in full page.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Multi BxSlider</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    img,
    li {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    table {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    .huge {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    section {
      min-height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="huge">
          <ul class="bx">
            <li data-idx="0">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x270/000/fff.png&text=1">
            </li>
            <li data-idx="1">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x270/000/0b0.png&text=2">
            </li>
            <li data-idx="2">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x270/000/fc0.png&text=3">
            </li>
            <li data-idx="3">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x270/000/0ff.png&text=4">
            </li>
            <li data-idx="4">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/480x270/000/b52.png&text=5">
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="cx">
            <li data-idx="0">
              <h2>Kafka</h2>
              <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and
                divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>
            </li>
            <li data-idx="1">
              <h2>Far and Away</h2>
              <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
            </li>
            <li data-idx="2">
              <section>
                <h2>Ordered List of Links</h2>
                <ol>
                  <li><a href="https://w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="https://example.com">Example</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Domain</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4">bxSlider-GitHub</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="https://bxslider.com/options">bxSlider-Options</a>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </section>
            </li>
            <li data-idx="3">
              <section>
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>TH</th>
                      <th>TH</th>
                      <th>TH</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>TD</td>
                      <td>TD</td>
                      <td>TD</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>TD</td>
                      <td>TD</td>
                      <td>TD</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>TD</td>
                      <td>TD</td>
                      <td>TD</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </section>
            </li>
            <li data-idx="4">
              <section>
                <h1>H1 Title</h1>
                <h2>H2 Title</h2>
                <h3>H3 Title</h3>
                <h4>H4 Title</h4>
                <h5>H5 Title</h5>
                <h6>H6 Title</h6>
              </section>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>Yikes that's an enormous cell!</td>
        <td>Why in the hell is that cell so HUGE!?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>The weight of this cell is crushing us...ack!</td>
        <td>Run for your lives! IT'S CELLZILLA!!!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var bx = $(".bx").bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
        onSlideBefore: goTo,
        slideMargin: 50
      });

      var cx = $(".cx").bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        controls: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        slideMargin: 50
      });

      function goTo($ele, from, to) {
        var idx = parseInt(to, 10);
        cx.goToSlide(idx);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not working :/ Tried on Opera

Comment: Please more details than just. "not working" How about errors reported on console?

Comment: Plz post an image of your browser screen. I only see the first image with no control to move/back.

Comment: How about using Chrome or Firefox? I heard they're giving them away for free, hurry before they're all gone! I don't know about your neck of the woods, but among the traffic that uses my JWPlayer videos, the use of Opera is half a percent. IE 9 beats Opera by a couple percents. It's your turn to post an image of what you see in Opera, it should  be amusing.

Comment: this works in FF :) But whats wrong with Opera :/

Comment: Click Opera's `help`, then click `about` what is your version? It might be the mixed protocols. I'll change them.

Comment: I have Opera 38.0, btw you missed the title bar :}

Comment: It's in each bottom half of the slides. A `<h2>`

Comment: Btw, look at this [chart](http://caniuse.com/usage-table). Opera is irrelevant it's average usage is overall 0.5% that's abysmal.

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout [unslider](http://unslider.com/). Haven't work with it yet, but it looks like something that you're looking for.

> Unslider uses a HTML element to wrap everything in, and puts all the slides inside that as an unordered list.
>   You can put any HTML you'd like inside each slide. Here's an example:

```
<div class="my-slider">
    <ul>
        <li>My slide</li>
        <li>Another slide</li>
        <li>My last slide</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So inside these `<li>` you could do the styling regarding the image and descriptions...

Comment: Could you plz help with the styling. I can't get it :/