# Creating first jQuery slideshow plugin, converting from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I was asking about a jQuery plugin with image, title and description [jQuery slide show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632222/sideshow-with-title-and-description). But can't find such. So tried to build a very small and easy [ugly] slide-show using only javascript. But there are some drawbacks, as in my script I have to hard code images, titles and descriptions. So I want to create a jQuery plugin from scratch which does only the same job as the script does, and also builds the slide-show on runtime.  So this will also be a tutorial on creating a basic slide-show plug-in.

The code I used for the easy, ugly slide-show controller

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
td {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 width: 420px;
 max-width:420px;
 text-overflow:ellipsis; 
}
span {
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 420px;
 max-width:420px;
 overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;
 border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td><img id="img" name="img" src="" title="Image" /></td> </tr>
<tr><td><span id="title">title</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="desc">description</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="<" onclick="back()" />
<input type="button" value=">" onclick="next()" /> 
<input type="text" id="idx" value="1" size="2" /> </td></tr>
</table></body>
<script>
var titles = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four"];
var descs = ["0 zer0", "1 one ", "2 two ", "3 three", "4 four"];
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var ttl = document.getElementById('title');
var dsc = document.getElementById('desc');
var idx = document.getElementById('idx');
var limit = titles.length-1;

function back()
{
 if (parseInt(idx.value) > 1)
  idx.value = parseInt(idx.value) - 1;
 img.src = 'images/image' + idx.value + '.jpg'; 
 ttl.innerHTML = titles[idx.value];
 dsc.innerHTML = descs[idx.value];
}

function next()
{
 if (parseInt(idx.value) < limit)
    idx.value = parseInt(idx.value) + 1;
 img.src = 'images/image' + idx.value + '.jpg'; 
 ttl.innerHTML = titles[idx.value];
 dsc.innerHTML = descs[idx.value];
}
</script>
</html>
```

I want it to be used as

```
<div id="main">
<img src="...." title="Title of image 1" data-desc="description of #1 image" />  
<img src="...." title="Title of image 2" data-desc="description of #2 image" />
</div>
```

Comment: You need to explain your question better.

Comment: So you want someone to show you how to reinvent the wheel so you can make a tutorial on reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @DelightedD0D exactly, you are just so brilliant

Comment: @Sourav I guess you are looking for something like this? [Simple way of creating jQuery Slider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233575/simple-way-of-creating-jquery-slider)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492797/slider-filereader-js-multiple-image-upload-incrementing-index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nivo slider](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider) .

You just have to mention description of an image in alt attribute and title of an image in title attribute.

And just attach the plugin to your wrapper element:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#main').nivoSlider(); 
});
```

Edit1:
A simple way to create such plugin

```
jQuery.fn.imgSlider = function( options ) {

    // default settings:
    var defaults = {
        textColor: "#000",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        fontSize: "16px",
        getTextFromTitle: true,
        getTextFromAlt: false,
        animateOpacity: true,
        animationDuration: 500,
        clickImgToGoToNext: true,
        clickImgToGoToLast: false,
        nextButtonText: "next",
        previousButtonText: "previous",
        nextButtonTextColor: "red",
        previousButtonTextColor: "red"
    };

    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {
        // Plugin code would go here...
    });

};
```

call the plugin

```
$( "div" ). imgSlider();
```

*Edit 2*

I have created a jQuery Image Slider Plugin.
**here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/shwetaM/rv93wubx/)** **with annotated code.**

Comment: I want to know how to create such plugin

Comment: There are many ways to create such plugins ... check the edited answer

Comment: @Sourav lol, I bet it would, then that tutorial would just about write itself ;)

Comment: @Sourav added an example link please check the answer. It may be useful.